# Limit using floor function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking at $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (-1)^{[[1/x]]}$. It's clear the limit doesn't exist. I'm struggling with incorporating the odd/evens into my usage of the floor function.

([[1/x]] denotes the floor function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $[[1/x]]=[1/x]$. Consider two sequnces $x_n=\frac{1}{2n}$ and $x'_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ and you get two different limits.

Comment: In my book, the notation is that $[[1/x]]$ is the floor function.

Comment: No big deal. I think that you wrote integer floor function twice.